# CSS animation questions

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to get the second div to slide in from the left while fading in, then once that has completed to have the third div slide to the left while fading out. What am I doing wrong?

The CSS I wrote will either just fade it in or have slide in but not both.

```
<div style="font-weight:bold;">
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">Sport</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">Entry $</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;"># Entries</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">Max</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">Time</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="row1">
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">NFL</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">$50</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">12</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">48</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">2:00ET</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div id="row2" style="display:none;">
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">NFL</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">$5</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">45</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">100</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">3:00ET</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div id="row3">
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">MLB</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">$10</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">1</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">10</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;">1:00ET</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

//CSS code I currently have right now
#row2 {
    left: -500px;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation: slide 2.0s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation: slide 2.0s fordwards;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    display: block !important;
}

#row3{
    -webkit-animation: slide1 2.0s backwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation: slide1 2.0s backwards;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    25%  { opacity: .25;}
    50%  { opacity: .50;}
    75%  { opacity: .75;}
    100% { left: 8px; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes slide {
    25%  { opacity: .25;}
    50%  { opacity: .50;}
    75%  { opacity: .75;}
    100% { left: 8px; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide1 {
    25%  { opacity: .75;}
    50%  { opacity: .50;}
    75%  { opacity: .25;}
    100% { left: -500px; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { display: none;}
}

@keyframes slide1 {
    25%  { opacity: .75;}
    50%  { opacity: .50;}
    75%  { opacity: .25;}
    100% { left: -500px; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { display: none;}
}
```

Comment: what is forwards and backwards never heard of such css properties ? try these http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: @saj Try reading this - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp

Comment: @saj forwards and backwards is used to determine what frame of the animation to keep once its done playing

Comment: @Banana cheers for that never knew it existed !!!

Answer (score 2):

have a look at a fixed <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/EpMaN/)**</kbd>

you had a few mistakes:

- its always "forwards" not "backwards", it simply tells the css what frame of the animation to keep once animation is done playing, "forwards" means keep the last frame, while "backwards" means keep the first frame.
- you misspelled and wrote "fordwards" on one of the lines.
- you set the `100%` tag multiple times, you must not do that, only set it once and put everything inside.
- you cannot adjust left property of static objects. so unless you set the divs position to absolute, relative or fixed, you need to use margin-left.

Comment: there are more mistakes here but you did not mention it, the OP animates the `left` but instead you use `margin-left` for no explanation. Also I would say ***you must NOT*** not ***you do not need***.

Comment: yea, i did fix his left to margin-left, jsut forgot to mention. ill update

Comment: it should be absolute or ***relative***, I would choose relative here.

Comment: Thank you all. The information you provided is helping me learn.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0%   { opacity: 0; margin-left: -500px; }
    100% { margin-left: 8px; opacity: 1; }
}
```

"left" seems not to be animatable in current versions of some browsers (it's simply not developed completely yet). But "margin-left" is. Make sure you provide keyframe at start and at end. The keyframes at 25%, 50% and 75% for slide are unnecessary then (except you want to make non-linear animations).